# Unable to read sqlite data and compare it to strings in python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So here I have some basic code for a simple user login.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info")
all_rows = cur.fetchall()
usernames = []
passwords = []
for row in all_rows:
    usernames.append(row[0])
    passwords.append(row[1])
print(usernames)
print(passwords)


class loginApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(loginPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

    def login_check(self, username, password):
        x = username.get()
        y = password.get()
        login_check_bool = False
        for i in range(len(usernames)):
            if x is usernames[i] and y is passwords[i]:
                login_check_bool = True
            else:
                self.switch_frame(badLogin)
                print(x + y)
        if login_check_bool is True:
            self.switch_frame(goodLogin)


class loginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Login to the Application", font="Arial 20 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Username: ", font="Arial 15").pack()
        ownUser = tk.Entry(self, width=24)
        ownUser.pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Password: ", font="Arial 15").pack()
        ownPass = tk.Entry(self, width=24, show="*")
        ownPass.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="LOGIN", command=lambda: master.login_check(ownUser, ownPass)).pack()


class goodLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="YOU'RE LOGGED IN!!!").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="RETRY", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(loginPage)).pack()


class badLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="WRONG!!!").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="RETRY", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(loginPage)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = loginApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

It seems to be working fine, however, I have one simple issue. I seem to be unable to compare the database value I got from the test-db to my passwords and username value. If I use a test login that has the username of l and the password of l, it works fine. Any solutions?

I also have the sqlite config of having a simple table in the test-db that has usernames (varchar(24)) and a password (varchar(24)). I don't know if that has anything to do with the fact that it doesn't work. Thanks!

PS. The print statements are for debugging, sorry.

Comment: "unable to compare" in what way? What is going wrong, specifically? What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening instead? Additionally, you are asking about a scenario where the comparison doesn't work, yet you only gave us an example of a scenario where it does work. Please give an example of your app failing to meet your expectations. Sample input, desired behaviour, and actual behaviour would be helpful.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. If we take an example user name I put into the database with the matching password (the set is vraj as the username and password as the password). We get the badLogin screen even though it should be a matching pair.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. You seem to have posted a lot of code that's not directly related to the question being asked.

Comment: Here, I added another username and password, vpro and password. Here is a video https://streamable.com/i4y7z

Comment: @BryanOakley I will try to do that next time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is" is not the correct way to compare strings in Python.

Replace this line:

```
if x is usernames[i] and y is passwords[i]:
```

with

```
if x == usernames[i] and y == passwords[i]:
```

And you should get past the current missbehavior (although the design have enough issues you might have other problems there)

**what?** Yes. The `is` operator just results in `True` when both operands are *the same* object. If you have a string hardcoded in the program-body, there is an implementation specific optimization that internalizes the string, and there is a chance of it yield `True` when compared with the use of `is` -but reading then from the database would not trigger this behavior.

The `==` operator, on the other hand, compares the actual string contents - and is the correct way of comparing strings or any other objects for equality.

**other issues?**
Plenty. To start with the fact you read all the contents of the database to two search-unfrendly, uncorrelated, memory structures, and from that point on, resort to a serch method that is really, really "manual" compared to either Python or SQLite's search and compare capabilities.

That is, you put all your DB login and passwords in two separate lists. You might just effect a query by the login inside `login_check`. If the query returns no results you have an incorrect login. If it returns a single result, you proceed to compare the password in the same row. That is an obvious-enough design for this app.

**Learn security from the start** So, you are learning more stuff, and building apps that have an UI and deal with databases - no need to not be concerned with security and privacy the right way from now: if you record the plain passowrd to your database, if it leaks, that is a major mishap for you, and a burden for all your users - (because they might re-use the same passwords elsewhere) - so, whenever you store a password, take your time to store using a one-way cryptographic algorithm - when comparing passwords, you run the same one-way algorithm on the typed-in password, and compare that value with the one stored on the DB. IF a bad buy takes hod of your DB data, there are no means to revert the encoded passwords back to the plaintext.  Python have good one-way crypto algorithms in the stdlib [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) module. Take a look there.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot thank you! Seems to be working now. Sorry for the trouble this may have caused! Also, will work on fixing the design, I'm pretty new to python!

Comment: NP. I took my time to expand the asnwer with some extra hints.